# Is there a way to limit which devices can approve TFA requests?

Tags: macos, two-step-authentication, two-factor-authentication

Is there a way to limit which Apple devices are able to approve TFA requests? For example, let's say I have the following devices:

- Macbook 1
- Macbook 2
- iPhone
- iPad

When TFA approval requests come in, can I limit it so that only `Macbook 1` and `iPhone` have permissions to approve the requests? In other words, I'd like for the other devices to be lower trust devices that are connected to my Apple ID but are not able to approve new devices or browsers trying to use my Apple ID.